# Symfony project shows directory listing index instead of index page

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I am new to Symfony, and I've just created a new project on Windows server + Php7.3 + Apache 2.4. 
The project folder is located at C:\Apache24\htdocs\symfony.

When I access that folder from my web browser, I see the directory listing page it should show the index page in the public folder.

Here is my code in apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:90>
    ServerAdmin abc@abc.com
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/symfony/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And i tried to use .htacess option as in Symfony guideline with install symfony/apache-pack, but no luck:

```
<VirtualHost *:90>
    ServerAdmin abc@abc.com
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/symfony/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

- the .htaccess file had been created in public folder.
- i have tried to install the demo application too, the same issue.
- Wordpress or other applications have been installed without issue.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you install PHP + Apache? Is it a manual installation? If so, maybe this guide starting points 7 & 8 helps (the installation part before is unix specific, but points 7 & 8 are general configuration for php+apache): https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Comment: Ya, i install manually for both on Windows OS, not using any WAMP tool like XAMPP.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't the `DocumentRoot` also be pointing to the [Symfony `public` directory](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#apache-with-mod-php-php-cgi)?

```
<VirtualHost *:90>
    ServerAdmin abc@abc.com
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/symfony/public"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/symfony/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```